# HTML to Excel using Button click Not working

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter, export-to-excel

I'm working on exporting the HTML table that I created directly to excel. I was able to do it by accessing the URL directly. However, button click and Ajax do not work.

**Trial 1:**

I created a dummy table and saved it in a variable.

```
function export_accounting(){
    //$test = "'".$this->input->post('table')."'";
    $test = '<table class="table table-striped table-bordered"><thead><tr><th>Agent</th><th>Date</th><th>Invoice Number</th><th>Customer Name</th><th>Product Code</th><th>Destination</th><th>Gross Amount</th><th>Commission</th><th>Discount</th><th>Net Amount</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><td>LLC KALYE</td><td>2018-01-03</td><td>ADC049810</td><td>SY TU, MELISSA</td><td>ACBOX</td><td>LUZ</td><td class="text-right">48.80</td><td class="text-right">3.68</td><td class="text-right">0.00</td><td class="text-right">48.80</td></tr><tr><td>&nbsp;</td><td>2018-01-03</td><td>ADC049811</td><td>RAMIREZ, ELMER</td><td>ACBOX</td><td>LUZ</td><td class="text-right">229.50</td><td class="text-right">13.56</td><td class="text-right">0.00</td><td class="text-right">229.50</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><th scope="row" class="text-right">278.30</th><th scope="row" class="text-right">17.24</th><th scope="row" class="text-right">0.00</th><th scope="row" class="text-right">278.30</th></tr><tr><td>OFFICE ACCOUNT</td><td>2018-01-03</td><td>ADC050183</td><td>QUESEA, NELSON</td><td>ACBOX</td><td>LUZ</td><td class="text-right">24.95</td><td class="text-right">0.00</td><td class="text-right">0.00</td><td class="text-right">24.95</td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><th scope="row" class="text-right">24.95</th><th scope="row" class="text-right">0.00</th><th scope="row" class="text-right">0.00</th><th scope="row" class="text-right">24.95</th></tr><tr><th scope="row" class="text-danger">GRAND TOTAL:</th><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><td></td><th scope="row" class="text-right text-danger">303.25</th><th scope="row" class="text-right text-danger">17.24</th><th scope="row" class="text-right text-danger">0.00</th><th scope="row" class="text-right text-danger">303.25</th></tr></tbody></table>';
    //$file = $this->input->post('control_number').".xls";
    $file = "test.xls";
    header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$file\"");
    header("Pragma: ");
    header("Cache-Control: ");
    echo $test;
}
```

This works when I access the URL directly.

**Trial 2:**

I used Ajax and made the variables in my export function dynamic. So when I click a button, it goes to the URL and sends the data needed.

```
$(document).on('click', 'button.export_report', function(){
  var data = $('div#export_table').html();
  var export_control_number = $(this).data('control_number');

  $.ajax({
      url: window.base_url+'mgtcomm/export_accounting',
      data: {'table': data, 'control_number': export_control_number},
  });
});
```

This does not work. It just echoes the data but not the export.

**Trial 3:**

I made the export button a submit button and putting back the dummy data for the sake of making it work.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('mgtcomm/export_accounting');?>">
    <div class="text-right"> <button class="btn btn-success export_report" type="submit">Export Report</button></div>
</form>
```

This does not work. It gives mo 404 error when I go to the URL the first time. But it downloads the file when I reload the URL.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon [this](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html) plugin just as I finished posting this question. This helped me achieve what I need.

Answer (score 0):

try put an `index.php` in the url.

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo base_url('index.php/mgtcomm/export_accounting');?>">
```

Comment: Hi @Session Start. I removed the index.php in my URLs. And I solved it using a super easy to use jquery plugin. Thanks for your comment.